# Access C# function from browser (JS)

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, printing

I need to create a client application and I wanted to write it a web client (since it's the easiest way to create a great UI and easy to deploy etc etc...)

The only problem is, I need to use some C# in the client application (to call a printing method for example which nodeJS doesn't handle well on windows)

What I tried :

- WPF WebBrowser control | Problem : works only with IE
- Self host C# webapi | Problem : seems stupid client should run mvc web api just to use C# function

clarification : I want my front end to be in html/css/js, backend in Node.JS and the client should be able to perform some C# via webbrowser control (window.external) or self hosted web api

P.S : A lot of people saying javascript can't run C#. I know. I'm asking for a creative bypass, that's the entire question

Never mind, you can close this question. I wanted creative solution, all I got was google searches, sad

Comment: c# cannot run on a browser. You **have to** create a web api for this to work

Comment: Did you read my entire question? it's not that long

Comment: You mentioned `node`. Are you talking about NodeJs? Please clarify the architecture of your solution.

Comment: I don't **have to** create a web api, I just listed another way of doing that using window.external. I was wondering if anyone knows of another way, maybe an open source project I'm not aware of?

Comment: I did read your question. You want to call c#? You have to create a web api or create a console app that Node calls from the backend

Comment: console app? Now that's interesting, how?

Comment: How do you use NodeJs on the client side? (you can call c# from NodeJs)

Comment: I don't know Node at all, but if you can call into Node from the browser (say, AJAX), you can create an `.EXE` Console Application ( that's how the project is called) which you could invoke from Node. Also, look [here](https://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/)

Comment: @OrBetzalel, running C# in a browser is not the easiest way to do that, if this is what you meant. However you can use Silverlight. The easiest way to make a client application for Windows is a Console, then you have Winforms and WPF desktop.

Comment: Yes but you if you want an easy, modern, cross platform application, winform/wpf is not the way to go

Comment: @OrBetzalel have you looked at using Xamarin (and Xamarin.Forms)?

Comment: It's for a commercial application so I prefer a free solution

Comment: You can try CefSharp as well: http://cefsharp.github.io/

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi, what OP asking for it's to run C# in a browser, whereas the link you've provided it's about running a browser in you C# application.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding then, but why did he evaluate the idea of using the `WebBrowser` control then? The way I understand it is he wants to write the UI in HTML/CSS using an embedded browser which can call some C# methods, which CefSharp can do. But again, maybe I'm misunderstanding, it's not very clear from the question.

Comment: @Szabolcs Dézsi Yep you understood perfectly, frontend in html/css/js, backend in Node.JS and the client should be able to perform some C# via webbrowser control (window.external) or self hosted web api

Comment: You can print from a browser without calling C# code. What does your printing function do? Can't you generate a PDF or similar?

Comment: @Dan Wilson I need to be a silent print

Comment: @Szabolcs Dézsi Went with your solution, works nicely. If you write it as an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments, you can achieve what you’re looking for with [CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/). It’s well maintained, uses Chrome’s rendering engine, offers hardware acceleration, you can invoke JS from C# and the JS code can invoke C# as well.